# Preserving data more than once

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I am writing some code in Stata and I have already used `preserve` once. However, now I would like to `preserve` again, without using `restore`.

I know this will give an error message, but does it save up to the new preserve area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, preserving twice without restoring in-between simply throws an error:

```
sysuse auto, clear

preserve
drop mpg

preserve
already preserved
r(621);
```

However, you can do something similar using temporary files. From `help macro`:

> *"...**tempfile** assigns names to the specified local macro names that may be used as names for temporary files.  When the program or do-file concludes, any
>   datasets created with these assigned names are erased..."*

Consider the following toy example:

```
tempfile one two three

sysuse auto, clear
save `one'

drop mpg
save `two'

drop price
save `three'

use `two'
list price in 1/5

     +-------+
     | price |
     |-------|
  1. | 4,099 |
  2. | 4,749 |
  3. | 3,799 |
  4. | 4,816 |
  5. | 7,827 |
     +-------+

use `one'
list mpg in 1/5

     +-----+
     | mpg |
     |-----|
  1. |  22 |
  2. |  17 |
  3. |  22 |
  4. |  20 |
  5. |  15 |
     +-----+
```